# image performance - setting image source temporarily stalls browser

Tags: javascript, drawimage, imagesource

I am searching for techniques to work with an image that is 30000 (width) by 2500 (height), which is about 4mb in size.

The image contains about 500 smaller "subimages", in which I index into the larger image to get to the small image(s).  Only one small image will be displayed at a time.  I am using drawImage to copy a portion of the larger image and render.  Smaller image height/width is 600 x 250 pixels.

As additional background, we do not need to visualize the large image, only index into it.

The loading technique is fine, downloading the 4mb takes some time but that is not the issue.  There are two issues that I am seeking to resolve:

1) Following load of the 4mb image, via ajax to base64, we set the image src.  Setting the src stalls the browser for a second or two.  The code to set the source is as follows:

```
    GlobPNG = document.createElement('img');
    l_src = "data:image/jpg;base64," + e.data;
    $(GlobPNG).attr({'width':'30000', 'height':'2500', 'display':'none', 'src': l_src });
```

2) The drawImage routine is based on mouse movements.  It typically works fine, but occasionally, it stalls the browser....again for a second or two.  The code to update and visualize is as follows:

```
    lCtx.canvas.width = lCtx.canvas.width;
    lCtx.drawImage(GlobPNG, imgXBegin, imgYBegin, 600, 250, 0,0,lCtx.canvas.width, lCtx.canvas.height);
```

I am wondering if there is a better technique.

Any suggestions are appreciated!